# Detect mouseover on element bottom margin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible with plain JavaScript or jQuery to detect a mouseover on an element bottom margin, ie when the mouse is over the element margin but not on the element contain itself?

It seems it's possible because the [Medium](http://medium.com) editor can display a link (a "plus" sign) when the mouse is over the bottom margin of paragraph elements, but not when the mouse is over the paragraph text. I have no idea how they achieve that. Here is how it works in Medium: http://d.pr/i/njS+

EDIT: 
Medium don't use nested elements, it is just the plain element with its bottom margin. See here: http://d.pr/i/X7Gb+

For a specific reason I can't use nested elements, and would like to do like Medium, just with the plain element and its margin bottom.

Comment: Are you sure it's really the margin and not a container DIV around the element?

Comment: Yes it seems to be the margin, there is no container DIV around the element, I've just edited the question with a screen capture showing more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, the margin isn't part of the element.  But you can use 2 nested DIVs.  Then detect whether the mouse is over the outer DIV but not over the inner DIV.  I'm sure that's how the Medium editor does it (although I can't check).

e.g. check using jQuery:

```
$('#outer').is(":hover") && !$('#inner').is(":hover")
```

Update:
In the example image from Medium, the outer DIV would be `#editor_4` and instead of the inner DIV, there are other elements, but the principle is (or could be) the same.

With many lines, it may be more efficient to set/clear boolen flags in mouseover events for each of the lines instead of selecting and testing each element every time.

Update2:
I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sAZXJ/27/) that implements this using a single boolean flag.

Comment: Thanks herman but Medium doesn't use nested DIVs, it's just the plain element with its bottom margin. I've just edited the question with a screen capture of Medium proving this. I'm very surprised that they can achieve this effect without nested elements.

Comment: Can you somehow invite me for collaboration so I can investigate?  I logged in with Twitter but can't post.

Comment: I just looked at the image.  They could be testing whether the mouse is over `#editor_4` but not over any of those `<p>` or `<hr>` elements.

Comment: Thanks herman, I've just sent a collaboration link to Medium through your website contact form. You should be able to create posts on Medium with it.

Comment: Can you add a note? Then once I save the post you should be able to create posts on Medium https://medium.com/about/8304190661d4 (I have to go offline now, will be back in a few hours).

Comment: Added a note, but, I already updated my answer with a jsFiddle that shows exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks you very much herman! I've tried your fiddle, and indeed it works exactly as expected. Your help has been very much appreciated. I've published the Medium post on which your left a note, and then I've deleted it, hopefully now you can post with Medium too.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to find if the cursor is over the margin bottom of an element but it's a bit tricky. We need to find the position, the height and the width of the element and bind a `mousemove` event on document.

**HTML**

```
<div id="margin">Margin</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    margin: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div.active {
    background: red;
    color: blue;
}
```

And the magic **JAVASCRIPT**

```
 var x, y,
        mar = {}; 
        mar.elm = $('#margin');
        mar.width = mar.elm.width();
        mar.height = mar.elm.height();
        mar.left = mar.elm.offset().left;
        mar.top = mar.elm.offset().top;
        mar.marginBottom = parseInt(mar.elm.css('margin-bottom'), 10);

  $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        x = e.offsetX;
        y = e.offsetY;

        if (x >= mar.left &&
            x <= (mar.width + mar.left) &&
            y >= (mar.top + mar.height) &&
            y <= (mar.top + mar.height + mar.marginBottom)) 
        {
            mar.elm.removeClass('active').addClass('active');
        } else {
            mar.elm.removeClass('active');
        }
  });
```

Here's a full exemple : [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ucJR/3/)

Comment: This fiddle takes into account multiple elements, and also left and right margin... with the commented code you can count top margin too... http://jsfiddle.net/4ucJR/6/